# Apply DRY to multiple loops throughout the file

Tags: javascript, optimization, dry

I am currently learning and trying to apply the principles of clean and modular code. As I was writing my application, I noticed that I looped through the same JSON object in different functions using the same code.

```
for(var i = 0; i < myJSONData.length; i++) {
    // do stuff with myJSONData[i]
}
```

This becomes redundant throughout the application.

```
var myJSONData = [/* array of objects */];

var myFunc = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < myJSONData.length; i++) {
        // do stuff with myJSONData[i]
    }
}

var anotherFunc = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < myJSONData.length; i++) {
        // do different stuff with myJSONData[i]
    }
}
```

How would I apply the DRY principle here and only write the loop once?

Comment: FYI, this might be a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: That depends on what you are doing in the loops and if there is code that runs in between the loops that affects the contents of `myJSONData`

Comment: If you're looping twice, there's nothing non-DRY about saying "LOOP" twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you present looks fine as it is. It is quite common to have a similar loop in several functions and that type of repetition is not necessarily a problem, as long as the code within the loops is not repeated.

However you could also consider reorganising as follows.

```
function myFunc(item) {
    // do stuff with item
}
function anotherFunc(item) {
    // do stuff with item
}
//...
myJSONData.forEach(myFunc);
// ...
mYJSONData.forEach(anotherFunc);
```

A nice side effect of this is that `myJSONData` can be defined within one function and does not need to have wider / global scope. `myFunc` and `anotherFunc` will just be passed one item at a time from it.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is common and often necessary. Really the only thing that isn't dry is the `for(...) {` and the closing `}`.

The term for this is boilerplate, which is code that adds little semantic value but is necessary to wire the code to the language. It's generally not DRY, and it's often regarded as more of a flaw in the language than in the code that one *must* repeat this stuff.

Javascript is a language that does solve this, however.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    foo(arr[i]);
}
```

Becomes

```
arr.forEach(foo);
```

So your code would become

```
jsonArray.forEach(function(a) { /* first loop */ });
// stuff
jsonArray.forEach(function(a) { /* second loop */ });
```

which, when read in English, is a perfectly sensible amount of repeating yourself.